# Problema com código de jogo de loteria

Tags: javascript, html, lógica

Basicamente o código é pra simular uma loteria, o usuário deve tentar adivinhar um dos números do array, se conseguir ele recebe os parabéns se não ele é avisado que errou, mas quando executo nenhuma ação acontece ao clicar no botão.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Traga seu código aqui, evite usar uma image. Você ainda pode utilizar a tag "Trecho de código JavaScript/HTML/CSS" que seu código poderá ser executado aqui mesmo, basta apertar CTRL + M.

Answer (score 0):

O id dos elementos é case-sensitive.

No trecho

```
var botaoAdivinhar = document.getElementById('Adivinhar');
```

troque a string do id 'Adivinhar' por 'adivinhar'